Are these statements about independent random variables true?
Let $E_X$ be any event which can be defined solely on random variable $X$ and $E_Y$ be any event which can be defined solely on random variable $Y$.
Just for clarification here are some possible examples of $E_X$:

$E_X=\{X^2=4\}$
$E_X=\{X>5\}$
$E_X=\{X \in S\}$ where $S$ is set of some values of r.v. $X$

The question is whether the following statements are true

r.v. $X$ and some event $A$ are independent $\iff$ any $E_X$ and $A$ are independent
r.v.'s $X$ and $Y$ are independent $\iff$ any $E_X$ and $E_Y$ are independent

I think I proved the 2nd statement for discrete r.v.'s but I would like to know  whether these statements are true in general. Intuitively they should be, but I would like to know for sure.
I do not ask any proofs, I just need answer yes/no. Though some references probably would be helpful.

Can you clarify what definition you are using for independence of random variables?

@Wei r.v.'s $X$ and $Y$ are independent $\iff$ $P(X=x, Y=y) = P(X=x)P(Y=y)$ for all possible $x,y$. And r.v. $X$ and event $A$ are independent $\iff$ $P(X=x, A) = P(X=x)P(A)$ for all possible $x$.

Your statements are true for discrete random variables, with the definition of independence that you are working with. Your statements are also true in general but for that you'll need to use a more general form of independence that also works for non-discrete random variables.
You asked for references - the Wikipedia page for independence of random variables would be a decent start.

Thanks a lot for the answer! Yes, sure, the definition of independence that I gave does not work for example for continuous r.v. I guess what you mean by more general form of independence is definition based on CDF, right? It is equivalent to the definition that I gave for discrete r.v. and it is equivalent to $f_{X,Y}=f_X(x)f_Y(y)$ ($f$ is PDF) for continuous r.v. Is it correct? If it is then it is great because those statements that I gave in my question allow to build very good intuition for independence.

Essentially yes, for real-valued random variables. Would still be worth giving the Wikipedia page a read for further context.

I guess you are talking about more abstract general things like $\pi$-systems, measurable spaces, Borel sets, etc. I will definitely try to learn probability theory in this more fundamental systematic way but for now I would like to go over these things more intuitively. So I really appreciate your answer. For now I guess that is it, I will close the question, thank you.
